# Why is actions on google use node js?

Tags: actions-on-google

Does anyone know the reasoning behind this language and framework choice? Seems like something like python would be better suited for machine learning, NLP type problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can certainly write your Action fulfillment in Python. Although Google provides a convenience library in node.js, the fulfillment is done via a webhook that receives JSON and is responsible for sending JSON back to Google.

Answer (score 0):

The client library does not provide NLP but is a convenience for the Conversation API for actions fulfillment.